# Making a list element invisible on mobile (responsive)

Tags: html, css, menu, visibility

I've been going through the internet for some solutions, but all of them failed or didn't even fit my problem.

I have a responsive site with a menu atop. The menu includes an item that is a dropdown as well:

```
        <header id="header">
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul><li><a href=".html">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu">
                        <a href=""><img src="images/list-icon.png" width="15px"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href=".html">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href=".html">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href=".html">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
       </header>
```

(I simplified it a bit, but I hope you get the idea)

I have solved responsivity with different style-sheets (so not @media thingys), and I am willing to make the dropdown menu item invisible in only one of the style-sheets (on smartphones). I've already tried these:

```
#header .submenu {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: none;
}
.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
#header nav ul li.submenu {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: none;
} 
#header .submenu {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: none;
}
.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
header nav ul li.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

(The menu-list is within a /header/ tag which has an id="header")

I am quite new to this whole responsive-thing, so this question might seem to be stupid or something, but ever since I was going through stackoverflow.com luckily you guys were always kind to each other. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it is a typo in your post, you're missing a `#` from `header nav ul li.submenu {}`.

```
#header .submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display:none;
}
#header nav ul li.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
} 
#header .submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display:none;
}
#header nav ul li.submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

Out of interest, could you explain why you don't want to use media queries?

---

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
   #header .submenu {
     display: none;
   }
}
```

This will hide on all `.submenu` within the `#header` on any device with a width of 1024px or less. For mobile you're probably look at around less than 600px.

Comment: Uhm, that whole last two sets of CSS are a mistake there, since .submenu was included before and yes the # is needed.

And well... At first I started reading a lot about responsive sites and this way seemed easier to modify. Now I see it is not, but due to some time restrictions I cannot redo the whole thing now

Comment: Did that solve your problem? --- Media queries are by far the easier option, make sure you look into them for your next site!

Comment: Unfortunately not. :(

Comment: Sadly not, but would it be possible to only solve this part of the responsivity with media query reference? I mean for example to remove anything connected to tables from the smartphone-css file and include a media query reference for that size? any ideas?

Comment: Well first of all thank you for your tireless help, but it is still not working. To be honest if it is this complex to solve (I've gone through related .js s as well) then it doesn't really worth it, not willing to waste your precious time on such thing

Comment: Then you must have conflicting code somewhere overriding. Try adding an !important to the end of the attribute just to rule that out.

Comment: Yaay, thanks a lot! I have no idea what can be overriding (especially since a reset css is also initialized when loading the smartphone-css) but this solved the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries. Glad it worked out! I would urge you to spend some time looking into why this has happened as using important can really be a pain later. Remember if a selector is more specific, it takes precedent! As well as the order in the style sheet, the last selector takes precedent over similar selectors. If it fixed your problem please up vote and accept!

Comment: Accepted, upvote is not available yet, but I guess I'll spend more and more time on this site from now on. Thanks again, I'll keep in mind your advice.

Answer (score 0):

For a media query reference, a good resource is:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Also, using boilerplates and preprocessors will help with a lot of responsive design problems.